# How to know if context.fail when invoking AWS Lambda function from Ruby SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When invoking an Amazon Web Service Lambda function from the ruby SDK is there any way of determining if the function encountered a context.fail?

ie. if I invoke an AWS Lambda function like this in the ruby sdk:

```
    resp = LAMBDA.invoke({
                  function_name: "cropSomeStuff", 
                  invocation_type: "RequestResponse", 
                  log_type: "Tail", # accepts None, Tail
                  payload: payload.to_json
              })
```

and the function encounters a `context.fail(err)`

`resp.successful?` still return true. I can look at the logs with `Base64.decode64(resp.log_result)`, however, I don't see an easy way to programmatically tell the function invocation failed at the ruby level.

Answer (score 1):

The [response object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/Lambda/Types/InvocationResponse.html) should include both a response code (`#status_code`) and an error string (`#function_error`). You can use either of these to detect an error:

Using `#function_error`:

```
unless resp.function_error.empty?
  # An error occured
end
```

Using `#status_code`:

```
unless resp.status_code.between?(200, 299)
  # An error occured
end
```

(Note that the documentation only specifies success as being "within the 200 range.")

There's no `#successful?` method in the documentation, so not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: It returns 200 regardless of wether it failed or not and the function_error only says that it's been handled.

Comment: `Handled` and `Unhandled` would both mean there was an error, but you'll likely need to parse the payload if you need specifics.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though parsing the `resp.payload` is the best course of action, if there is an error, the only key in that response dictionary will be `errorMessage`. 200 is returns so long as the function was invoked, and it's better to deal with the cases by looking at the returned result passed to a `context.fail`.